# Grails interprets the json to find the action method?

Tags: grails

Considers the following action in Grails 2.1.1

```
class ActionController {

    static allowedMethods = [submit: 'POST']

    def submit() {            
        render([ok: true, data: request.JSON] as JSON)
    }
}
```

The following command :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/backoffice/action/submit \ 
            -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
            -d '{"foo":"bar"}'
```

returns

```
{"ok" : true, "data" : {"foo" : "bar"}}
```

**BUT** if in the json I have an element called `action`, then Grails will try to find an action with the name equals to the value of that element !

For instance :

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/backoffice/action/submit \ 
            -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
            -d '{"foo":"bar","action":"bar"}'
```

results to a **404 error** because grails is trying to find the uri `/action/bar.dispatch` !!

How I can disable this weird feature ?

My `UrlMappings.groovy` :

```
 static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"(parseRequest: true){
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

Does the behaviour is due to the `parseRequest=true` ? I use this parameter to be able to use CommandObject from json.

Comment: Can you share the relevant bits of your `UrlMappings`?  Do you have `parseRequest:true` anywhere in them?  Also, what version of Grails?

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. I use grails 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `parseRequest:true`, which parses the posted JSON and adds its values to `params`.  If the JSON includes `action` this will set `params.action`, which in turn will affect which controller action is executed.

It may be worth you submitting a JIRA report to http://jira.grails.org to ask for some sort of mechanism to exclude certain parameters from parseRequest, or to change the precedence so that parameters extracted from the URL at UrlMappings time override those provided in the JSON rather than vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks Ian, so for the moment I have no other option than disable parseRequest or to not use json element called `action`.

Comment: I had a look to jira.grails.org and I found this issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7479. It seems the same problem occurs when a form contains a field named `action`, and the grails team doesn't want to fix this.

Comment: @tbruyelle the "won't fix" on that is that they won't stop treating "action" as a special parameter name, which is fair enough as it's baked into the framework in so many ways.  But they might be receptive to a request for an option to tell `parseRequest` to ignore certain parameter names - you wouldn't be able to use `action` in your JSON, but conversely if someone did accidentally or maliciously include it it would be good if it could be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try specific mapping, so Grails won't try to search for action name in parameters. Like this:

```
static mappings = {
    "/action/submit"(controller: 'action', action: 'submit', parseRequest: true)
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"(parseRequest: true)
}
```

UrlMappings work from specific to general rules, so first rule should take precedence.